# Can I define constructor without arguments in C?

Tags: swift

I have a C code:

```
static __inline__ __attribute__((__always_inline__))
__attribute((swift_name("Test.init()")))
test_t test_init(void) { /* ... */ }
```

And test Swift code:

```
let test = Test()
```

The code is compiled, but function *test_init* not call.

If I add test argument and call init with him, my method * test_init * is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For structures imported from C the compiler creates an `init()` initializer which takes no arguments and sets all members to zero. For example

```
__attribute((swift_name("Test")))
typedef struct {
    int a;
} test_t;
```

is imported to Swift as

```
public struct Test {
    public var a: Int32
    public init()
    public init(a: Int32)
}
```

as one can see with "Navigate -> Jump to Generated Interface" in Xcode.

You can create additional init methods in C, but you cannot *replace*
existing init methods.
(One could argue that the compiler should as least *warn* that the
 C function with the Swift name "Test.init()" will be ignored in Swift, so you might consider to file a bug report.)

If you want to define another init method taking no arguments in C
then you have to give it a dummy `Void` argument:

```
__attribute((swift_name("Test.init(v:)")))
static __inline__ __attribute__((__always_inline__))
test_t test_init(void) {
    test_t t = { 3 };
    return t;
}
```

and call it as

```
let test = Test(v: ())
print(test) // Test(a: 3)
```

Comment: Why default init override my implementation? And why not warning/error?

Comment: @qRoC: You can *override* methods only by subclassing, not via extensions and not for structs. (Imagine you could define your own `String.init` code which overrides the default initializer ...) – But a warning would be appropriate, I cannot tell you why it is not issued.

Comment: I told about "override" on translate level, not polymorphism.

Comment: Ok, 0044 - Importing as static method or init is not supported